# how to convert an array to a multidimensional array

Tags: sql, postgresql

how do i convert such an array {2,3,4} to {{2,TRUE}, {3,TRUE}, {4,TRUE}} in postgres

i tried using unnset without any breakthrough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `unnest` followed by `array_agg`

```
with tab as (
select '{2,3,4}'::text[] a
),
tab1 as (
select unnest(tab.a) a, 'TRUE' b from tab
)
select array_agg(array[a,b]) from tab1;

array_agg                   |
----------------------------+
{{2,TRUE},{3,TRUE},{4,TRUE}}|
```